# Graphics causing solid white button

Tags: vb.net

I'm coding Conway's game of life. My grid is entirely in a picture box but when I load the form the back button in the upper right is completely white. Refreshing the form fixes the button but makes it incredibly laggy. Every other button shows up fine, just the back button is broken. How can I fix this?

```
Option Strict On

Public Class frmGame
    ' Declaring public variables
    Public bmp As Bitmap
    Public G As Graphics
    Public WithEvents speed As Timer
    Public grid(50, 40) As Boolean
    Public input(50, 40) As Boolean
    Public intGens As Integer = 0
    Public change As Boolean = False
    Public P As New Pen(Color.Black)
Private Sub picGrid_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles picGrid.Paint
    ' Loads bitmap, graphics, etc and prepares to begin simulation

    ' Creates graphics device
    bmp = New Bitmap(600, 480)[enter image description here][1]
    picGrid.Image = bmp
    G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)

    ' Defining variables for grid
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Dim y As Integer = 0

    ' Draws grid
    For y = 0 To 480
        For x = 0 To 600
            G.DrawRectangle(pen:=P, x:=x, y:=y, width:=12, height:=12)
            x += 12
        Next
        x = 0
        y += 12
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub btnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
    ' Hides rules form, shows main menu form
    frmMainMenu.Show()
    Me.Hide()

End Sub

Private Sub frmGame_FormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    ' Frees memory when form is closed
    G.Dispose()
    bmp.Dispose()
    speed.Dispose()

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This can happen when a Paint event handler for a control runs over and over, not giving any subsequent controls a chance to paint.  Another noticeable side-effect is that the UI thread burns 100% core.  And yes, the code in this snippet does just that.  Assigning the picGrid.Image property forces a repaint.  Do this only once, the constructor is a good place.  If you need to change the bitmap content for some reason then use picGrid.Invalidate() so the new bitmap content is visible.  You probably want to use a Timer to do this so the game changes are observable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure do I understand your problem, nor I can recreate it with code provided.
But I can recommend some thing's that can help you.

First of all do not use Control.Refresh() while working with drawing, use instead Control.Invalidate() & Control.Update(), that may fix lag issue.

Do you relay need 2 forms (that i understand is the root of problem)?
Instead of hiding form, hide PictureBox (.Visible = False) and show other controls you need at that moment.